# Hardware Suggestions for Semi Truck Computing

Tags: hardware

Anyone out there have experience deploying computers in semi trucks?  I'm looking for something relitively cheap that would:

1. support external scanner and/or
   RFID readers (i.e. USB and/or serial
   support)
2. be permanently affixed
3. maintain a network connection at
   least most of the time
4. run a windows based operating system
5. run off the truck's power
6. easy navigation (touch screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you basically want to take hardware designed for a forklift warehouse and put it in a truck.

Check out: http://www.motorola.com/Business/US-EN/Business+Product+and+Services/Mobile+Computers/Vehicle-mounted+Computers

Regarding requirement #1, if this is fixed cab-mounted I have a hard time seeing a dude with a really long USB cable stringing it around to the trailer, but you may want to revise your question to clarify whether this computer should be removable or exactly what you need to accomplish with barcode and RFID...

Comment: Thanks for the link. Excellent suggestion. I didn't think about forklift solutions. Definitely earns an up vote. BTW, as odd as it sounds the requrements as listed above are correct in our scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Panasonic toughbook, like a CF-19,  for the computer, and [this](http://www.ledco.net/) company makes killer docking equipment. For internet, get an aircard and use a VPN connection. The TBs have both USB and serial ports.